# Connection Problems between Visual Studio and MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio, database-connection

I have almost spent a day but still can't find the proper solution. I am trying to connect my DropList component in Visual Studio with MySql database. DropList component is as follows:-

[image]

Server Explorer is also showing a valid database connection:

[image]

While choosing a data source for my Droplist component, Test Connection shows that everything working fine:
[image]

Selected all columns available in the respective Table:
[image]

Here comes the Issue, in the next screen when I click on Test Query, this error pops up:
[image]
I have tried creating the DB again as well as resetting the settings of both, VS and MySQL, still no success. Can anyone please guide me through this process of how to pass this error. Using Latest version of VS and MySQL. Correct Server Name, Username and Password also entered.
I have also cleared the VS Cache and other local app data, still not able to pass through this error

Comment: What does the code behind look like?

Comment: @WEI_DBA There is no code as I just created a database with tables and then trying to connect it with Visual Studio's droplist component. Actually working with the ASP .NET learning

Comment: To me, how can you put multiple columns into 1 drop list?

Comment: Same issue while selecting a single or multiple columns @WEI_DBA

Comment: If you check `save my password` in the connection properties, does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is also not working

Answer (score 1):

You might want to go back and check your steps:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-making-a-connection.html

Comment: I did everything according to it. It does appear under the Data Connections but it still does not pass the Test Query windows screen

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing worked. I migrated from MySQL to Microsoft SQL Server 2017 and everything worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for your support :)

Comment: We have saved this city! Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, even after trying everything, I was not able to make all this work with MySQL Database. I repeated all the similar steps, as explained in my question, by moving to Microsoft SQL Server 2017, and it worked like a charm just in seconds, without any errors. Attaching the picture below after migrating to Microsoft SQL Server 2017 from MySQL 2017 :
[image]